# android studio can't download complete android.support.v7.widget

Tags: android

I ought to use `AppCompatTevtView`, which is in the package `android.support.v7.widget`
But after adding compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'` to `gradle` and sync, I get only part of the package which doesn't include the `AppCompatTextView.class`.
What should I do?

Comment: please post your build.gradle and your logcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCompatTextView was initially released with [AppCompat v22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html). So you will need to update the version that you are syncing with gradle. I believe the latest version is 23.4.0.

Comment: Thank you!  `AppCompatTextView` appears in the `AppCompat 22.1.0`. But there's another problem.  It's says NoSuchMethodError `setSupportBackgroundTintList`..... So which version should I use. And how can I find out which to use. Thanks again!